# skip a value in one dimension of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array whose shape is (72, 671). Typically I select everything across the first dimension like this:

```
new_var = old_var[0:72]
```

However, for one file, I need to skip #18 across the first dimension. In other words, I want to select 0:17 and then 19:72 (or however you would write that correctly based on what is/isn't included). I have tried:

```
new_var=old_var[0:18,19:72]
```

but this only selects 0:18 in the first dimension and then 19:72 in the second. at least this is what I think it's doing, since the length of the resulting variable is 18. I can't find how to correct the syntax, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html)

```
old_var = np.random.random((72,671))
new_var = old_var[np.r_[0:18,19:72]]
new_var.shape
```

Output:

```
(71, 671)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use fancy indexing:

```
a[list(range(18)) + list(range(19, 72))]
```

Or `np.vstack`:

```
np.vstack((a[:18], a[19:]))
```